# Using Puppet for changing permissions of registry keys owned by TrustedInstaller

Tags: windows, registry, puppet

I'm trying to set all Windows 10 connections to `metered` to block automated updates. This requires editing values under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost` but Puppet Agent (running as `LocalSystem`) is not able to modify these values throwing errors like:

```
Error:/Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/Registry_value[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost\Default]: Could not evaluate: Unexpected exception from Win32 API. detail: (Access denied.). ERROR CODE: 5. Puppet Error ID: F46C6AE2-C711-48F9-86D6-5D50E1988E48
```

because the key is owned by `TrustedInstaller`.

Is it possible to modify these values in an automated way?

**Update.** The problematic part of `site.pp`:

```
node default {
  registry_value { 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost\3G':
    ensure  => present,
    type    => dword,
    data    => "2",
  }
  registry_value { 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost\4G':
    ensure  => present,
    type    => dword,
    data    => "2",
  }
  registry_value { 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost\Default':
    ensure  => present,
    type    => dword,
    data    => "2",
  }
  registry_value { 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost\Ethernet':
    ensure  => present,
    type    => dword,
    data    => "2",
  }
  registry_value { 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost\WiFi':
    ensure  => present,
    type    => dword,
    data    => "2",
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the manifest as part of your question? Thanks!

Comment: @ferventcoder Done.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a permissions issue, where `LocalSystem` just doesn't have the credentials to change those registry values. You can possibly do one of the following:

- add LocalSystem to the right groups (using the group resource) so that it would have the proper permissions so that you can adjust those keys (a quick search doesn't look like this is a group account, rather a special account)
- use an exec to give `LocalSystem` write access to those keys prior to making the changes
- possibly grant a privilege that is translated to TrustedInstaller (a quick search doesn't turn this up as a possibility either)

It looks like you will need to something like a cacl.exe call to set the permission, overriding TrustedInstaller as the owner and granting LocalSystem ownership and then privileges there. Please research first to understand the implications of this prior to making the change and how to reverse the setting once you have made it, if you want to reverse it.

Side note: The ACL module doesn't yet handle the registry for permissions, but it could in the future.

Comment: I'll run some tests using SubInACL (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23510) as described here http://www.askvg.com/windows-tip-take-ownership-permission-of-registry-keys-from-command-line/ Another way could be pure PS as shown here https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/brad_rutkowski/2008/09/29/set-acl-on-registry-key/